# Adding to arraylist unexpected behavior

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm not sure what is going on here. Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    al.add(i);

for(Integer i : al)
    System.out.println(al.get(i));

al.add(2,8); //should add the value 8 to index 2? 

System.out.println();
for(Integer i : al)
    System.out.println(al.get(i));
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

0
1
7
8
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Why is it adding in 7 and 8...and where did 9 go?

Comment: If you already have a reference to the Integer in each for loop why are you calling Arraylist.get(i)? why not just print the current Integer i for testing?

Comment: your for loops (`for (Integer i : al)`) are really foreach loops... they give you access to the elements of a collection; you don't need to touch the collection within the loop. In other words, each `i` is an integer from inside the collection, not an index like in the first (and only) for loop

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are getting this behavior because you are calling `get()` using the very `Integer`s contained in the `ArrayList`:

```
for (Integer i : al)
    System.out.println(al.get(i));   // i already contains the entry in the ArrayList

al.add(2,8); //should add the value 8 to index 2? 

System.out.println();
for (Integer i : al)
    System.out.println(al.get(i));   // again, i already contains the ArrayList entry
```

Change your code to this and all will be fine:

```
for (Integer i : al)
    System.out.println(i);
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
8    <-- you inserted the number 8 at position 2 (third entry),
2        shifting everything to the right by one
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the enhanced loop, and then printing the value using `get`; You should either print values at all indexes with `get`, or use enhanced loop without `get`. Better yet, use [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(boolean[])) for printing to avoid this kind of confusion:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    al.add(i);
Arrays.toString(al);
al.add(2,8);
Arrays.toString(al);
```